# Image not vertically centred despite using table and table-cell

Tags: html, css

I've tried to use `display: table` in the parent div and `display: table-cell` in the child div as seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ENGQG/) but I can't seem to get the image vertically aligned. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="body_splash">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/
commons/thumb/a/a3/Cc.logo.circle.svg/64px-Cc.logo.circle.svg.png"/> 
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.body_splash {
    width: 378px;
    float: left;
    display:table;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
}
.body_splash img {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}​
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What else will be in the box? There may be a more backwards-compatible solution, e.g. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/ENGQG/1/) will work in IE all the way back to version 7.

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff just the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Try [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SjLSz/1/)***

```
<div class="table">
  <div>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a3/Cc.logo.circle.svg/64px-Cc.logo.circle.svg.png"/> 
  </div>
</div>​

.table {
  display: table;
  float: left;
  width: 378px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

.table > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}​
```

Comment: Quick question, since I'm slightly mystified: why does this work, when the original doesn't? (and why would this work, when having the outer div simply set to `display: table`, and the inner div containing the float, width, etc. not work correctly?)

Comment: @Nightfirecat `vertical-align` applies to the children of the element in which it is declared.  You're saying "Middle-align all of my *children*", not "Middle-align me".

Comment: @SperanskyDanil I'm not the asker, I'm somebody else who thought your answer needed some clarification, since I didn't understand *why* it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If the box is a fixed size, use this: [Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/ENGQG/2/).

It absolutely positions the image inside the box.

Also look at these:

[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/ENGQG/3/)

[Demo 3](http://jsfiddle.net/ENGQG/4/)